# What is the name of this main character cliche?

Tags: character

I know that there is a name for this cliche but I can not remember it or find it anywhere. The cliche consist in the main character matching some specific conditions, and it is usually referred to using the name of one of the first famously known characters that matched these conditions:

The conditions are:

- They do not have a defined personality or strong personality traits.
- They might have very few lines in the script considering they are the main character.
- They are very charismatic and most of the other characters love or envy them despite their lack of dialogue and personality.
- Everything that happens in the plot involves them in some way, like the whole world orbits around them.
- They have a unique ability, a superpower, or they become an expert in a complex field in very little time.
- They end up in a relationship with the most attractive character or with the one they are attracted to.

This cliche usually means that the author wrote the main character thinking of themselves, and it is how they see themselves, how they want to be or a combination of both.

Comment: I disagree with these VTC choices.  There is an abundance of information given, and the identification reason is used for posters seeking names of shows or movies.  That being said, I don't believe what the OP is seeking exists and may be subject to a number of opinions.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger I'm sorry, I thought this would fit here. But you are wrong about the last part, I was given as an answer exactly the name I was looking for days before you posted this comment, so yes, I was looking for something that exists and has a name. Althought I thought it was more of a movie thing, not a fanfic thing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is known as a "Mary Sue"

[Warning: TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MarySue)

(Not sure about "says very little")

And according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Sue)..

> portrayed as inexplicably competent across all domains, gifted with unique talents or powers, liked or respected by most other characters, unrealistically free of weaknesses, extremely attractive, innately virtuous, and/or generally lacking meaningful character flaws. Usually female and almost always the main character, a Mary Sue is often an author's idealized self-insertion, and may serve as a form of wish-fulfillment. Mary Sue stories are often written by adolescent authors.